# Check if string is a number

Tags: constraints, uml, modeling, operation, ocl

```
================
|    Person    |
|--------------|
|- id : String |
|--------------|
================
```

I have class `Person` with property `id` that is `String` type. I have to check that `id` is a number that contains 11 digits. I thinking about something like this:

```
context Person::id:String
inv:    self.id->forAll(l|l.oclIsTypeOf(Integer))
        and
        self.id.size() = 11
```

but I have feeling that is not correct.

**EDIT.**

Now im sure it's not correct, 
`l.oclIsTypeOf(Integer)` always return `false`, because is `oclIsTypeOf` should be only called on `OclAny`, when `id` is a `String` type.

**EDIT 2. (Solution)**

I solved it like this:

```
context Person::id:String
inv:    not self.id.toInteger().oclIsInvalid()
        and
        self.id.size() = 11
```

Solution provided by `Vincent Aranega` below should works too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not so much methods on `String`, but the `toInteger` one can help you there. It returns the `Integer` value of a `String` or `Invalid` if the string cannot be converted to an `Integer`. So:

```
context Person::id:String
inv:    not self.id.toInteger().oclIsUndefined() 
        and self.id.size() = 11
```

should do the trick! (tested with success in Acceleo)